# How to also include tags in this kind of expression?

Tags: python, html, django

I couldn't seem to get this code running

> ```
> {%  for student in students %}
> {{<th>student.Last_name</th>}}
> {{<th>student.First_name</th>}}
> {{<th>student.Email</th>}}
> {{<th>student.Contact</th>}}
> {{<th>student.Course</th>}}
> {%  endfor %}
> ```

This works though, but getting a messy output

> ```
> {%  for student in students %}
> <th>{{student.Last_name}}</th>
> <th>{{student.First_name}}</th>
> <th>{{student.Email}}</th>
> <th>{{student.Contact}}</th>
> <th>{{student.Course}}</th>
> {%  endfor %}
> ```

something like this

> Last_name First_name Email Contact Course Last_name First_name Email Contact Course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second attempt is closer to being what I think you want.  You are missing the `<tr>` tags to start a new row for each student

```
{% for student in students %}
  <tr>
   <td>{{student.Last_name}}</td>
   <td>{{student.First_name}}</td>
   ...
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```